# tkinter Button widget 'inside' another button widget-tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to make an application, in which I need to place a tkinter button widget-'b1', inside another tkinter button widget-'b2'.
b2,however disappears and appears only after mouse is hovered over it.

Made a simple code without using OOP. Firstly made a master root window,added button 'b1'. Then using 'b1' as a master, added button 'b2'. The callbacks of both buttons are different. The problem is,button 1(in light blue color) appears normally visible. However second button(in red color) doesnt gets displayed. It appears only when you hover the mouse over it.

```
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()

b1=tk.Button(root,height=7,width=10,bg='light blue',command=print('B1'))
b1.place(x=0,y=0)

b2=tk.Button(b1,height=3,width=5,bg='red',command=print('B2'))
b2.place(x=2,y=2)

root.update()
```

Is it possible that both buttons are displayed simultaneously?.
Help is appreciated. Thanks in advance
This version of code is just for simplification. Later will implement more buttons and OOP as well. Sorry for mistakes if any.

Comment: `command=` needs function's name without `()` and arguments - it is called "callback". If you need assign function with arguments then use `lambda` - `commad=lambda:print('B1')`

Comment: use `root.mainloop()` instead of `root.update()`

Comment: code works correctly on Linux Mint - if I only use `mainloop()` **EDIT:** it has only problem with clicks on B1 when I click B2 and move mouse from B2 to B1. I have to move outside B1 and move back to B1

Comment: Thanks @furas. About 'command', yes, my mistake. Sorry for that.In my application code I am using lambda.

Comment: @furas,tried using root.mainloop, but still doesnt work. button 2 still shows only during hovering. I am using windows 10.

Comment: so problem is only on Windows. And Linux has problem with clickes on Button. It is rather unusuall to put Button in Button and maybe nobody expect this situation. You may try to use `Frame` instead of one `Button` and bind mouse events to `Frame` so it will be clickable.

Comment: @furas, might be only with windows. Next option will be using canvas or frame as you suggested. Will try something more if I can. however Thanks for your help:)